# Creating widgets using textual templates or a DSL [e.g. YAML or JSX]

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a standard flutter pattern / package to instantiate components of UIs by means of specifications stored in YAML-like files?

While I could certainly write this:

```
   Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
```

I'd probably prefer to load some YAML-like description, which in turn would create this widget hierarchy.

The template/DSL would need to have slots where other widgets could be inserted programmatically and would have to hook up to logic written in code.

**Q: Does something like this exist?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to this is no.

The long answer is... still no. But there is interest in the community for some sort of DSL and I'd be very surprised if one isn't developed at some point. Whether it will have official support and tooling support is another question (there is work underway to allow more extensible custom build steps which could definitely simpifly this). See [this flutter github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11609) for a very extended (and sometimes heated) discussion about a DSL (namely JSX but it suggests that if flutter were to support JSX it would be through a mechanism enabling other DSLs as well).

Comment: I don't need any point in having JSX or anything similar in flutter. JSX is here for react because the original syntax is horrible. While flutter's syntax is already excellent

Comment: @RémiRousselet I personally agree, but not everyone will. Everyone has their own preference (e.g. the OP), and there are certain benefits to a DSL in that it can be designed to limit the ability to write whatever absolute nonsense you want that still somehow works, or pre-render a simulation of the actual result (i.e. YAML does this fairly well) for a quicker write-design cycle (not needed in flutter =]) But to anyone reading this, I'd suggest spending a few days writing flutter code before saying you absolutely need a DSL.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a simple Transpiler that converts JSX to Flutter classes in here:

[Flutter JSX Github](https://github.com/danialdezfouli/flutterjsx)

[npm i -g flutterjsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flutterjsx)

[Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oj1JMSurphA)

Answer (score 0):

There's a substitute for your issue, try [here](https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_widget).

With dynamic widget package,you can create dynamic widgets by defining a json string, and also you can add custom click event for the custom widgets.

Hope this helps.